# Basic OpenGL lighting not working on my Mac

Tags: macos, qt, opengl, lighting

I've been working with OpenGL for a few months. We have started coding basic shaders in class and we have a Qt+OpenGL project to do. It's a simple one: an interactive 3d scene viewer. We've been given the starting code that loads .obj files, places them in the scene and then lets us rotate with the mouse.

I have a really weird problem here that my teacher hasn't been able to explain. We're using GL_LIGHT0 with its default parameters:

```
glEnable(GL_LIGHTING); 
glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
```

This is the only inicialization. The light's direction and position should be the same as the eye's. And this is how it works when I run the program in Ubuntu; i load the model of a cup and as I rotate, light rotates with my eye and I can see all its faces lighted up.
However, under Mac OS X 10.6.8, it's not working. The light stays fixed and all the faces that are facing other directions are black.
I've tried other lights, I've tried loading the identity in MODELVIEW and then specifying position and direction myself, I've tried re-downloading the code, re-compiling it and running it and still the same error.

The program needs some .dylib files that I link using soft links (I don't think this is the problem, though). The problem is not in the code since it works in other systems.
Is it possible that the Mac implementation is different? How can I test this? Thanks!

Edit: Here is a larger piece of code:

```
void GLWidget::initializeGL() {
    glClearColor(0.8f, 0.8f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING); 
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);

    resetCamera();  // sets VRP, OBS...
}

void GLWidget::paintGL( void ) { 
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );

    setProjection();
    setModelview();

    drawAxes();

    pscene.render();
}

void drawAxes() {
    float L = DRAW_AXES_LENGTH;
    glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glColor3f(1,0,0); glVertex3f(0,0,0); glVertex3f(L,0,0); // X
    glColor3f(0,1,0); glVertex3f(0,0,0); glVertex3f(0,L,0); // Y
    glColor3f(0,0,1); glVertex3f(0,0,0); glVertex3f(0,0,L); // Z
    glEnd();
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
}
```

These are the functions related to lighting. As I said, LIGHT0 is set once inside initializeGL. I tried to set its position in paintGL but it didn't work either.

----- EDIT 2 -----
I found a solution. Inside drawAxes, just before returning, add:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glPushMatrix();
glLoadIdentity();
GLfloat pos[] = {0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f};
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, pos);
glPopMatrix();
```

Why is this? After disabling and re-enabling it stops working?

Comment: It does not only matter that you call those functions, but also where in your program's execution flow. Please post some minimal example source code showing the problem.

Comment: While I was editing and copying my code, I came up with a new idea. It consists in re-define the GL_LIGHT0 parameters inside drawAxes, after drawing them all. Why is this? Shouldn't be enough defining them once in the inicialization? (Thank you for your answer, it helped me find a relatively easy solution!)

Comment: OpenGL is a state machine, and a "one time initialization" actually makes little to no sense with OpenGL. You should set all state right when you need it, in the right time. A global initGL function is actually a pretty silly thing. Get rid of it.